# How to optimize a part of my controller which will be repeated in several others

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `store` function in my controller which I use to add data to my `model`.

In this store function, I have a piece of code that is used to add an expense in the ʻexpends` table

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $model = Model::create([
        'name' => $request->name
    ])

    if ($request->add_expends == true) {
        Expend::create([
            'amount' => $request->amount
        ])
    }
}
```

The problem is, this piece of expense add code is used on multiple controllers (more than 10) across my application.

Is there a way to make this code reusable?

This is quite annoying because if I have to make a change I would have to do it in ten controllers and that's a problem.

Example of what I want to avoid :

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $model = Model2::create([
        'name' => $request->name
    ])

    if ($request->add_expends == true) {
        Expend::create([
            'amount' => $request->amount
        ])
    }
}

public function store(Request $request) {
    $model = Model3::create([
        'name' => $request->name
    ])

    if ($request->add_expends == true) {
        Expend::create([
            'amount' => $request->amount
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: there are multiple models when storing you need to add a record to this expends table?

Comment: You can create a model `created` event. Take a look: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-model-events-getting-started

Comment: @lagbox yes multiple models, when I store data on my Model2, or Model3, I can also add an expense. But that means that following my method, I have to do it in each controller of each model ... it's not great

Comment: You can create a new component and put your code in it. Component is extends of the controller

Comment: @Abutouq can I have an example? thanks

Comment: you could just add a method to the base controller like `addExpends` and pass that the request .. then you can call that method in each controller ... its not making it automatic but it is creating a single point for that functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would use some trait.
For example create a folder `app/Http/Controllers/Traits` and put there your trait `ExpendTrait`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Traits;

Trait ExpendTrait {

    private function createExpend()
    {
        if (request()->add_expends == true) {
           Expend::create([
               'amount' => request()->amount
           ]);
        }    
    }
}
```

Now use it in each of your controllers

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Traits\ExpendTrait;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    use ExpendTrait;          

    public function store(Request $request) {
       $model = Model::create([
         'name' => $request->name
       ]);

       $this->createExpend();
    }
}
```